# Image Animation in WPF

Tags: wpf, animation

I am doing a small application which tries to do animation with an Image. I want the image to come into view [image] like this . How do I go about doing it in WPF using C# Code? Thank You

Answer (score 1):

You can put the image into a `Canvas`, and animate its position and size. [Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms744833.aspx) is an example.

For choosing the moment to begin the animation in the C# code, you can use something like that:

(XAML)

```
<Canvas x:Name="container" ...>
    <Canvas.Resources>
        <Storyboard x:Key="MyAnimation">
            <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames ... />
            ...
        </Storyboard>
    </Canvas.Resources>

    <Image x:Name="image" .../>
</Canvas>
```

(C#)

```
var a = container.FindResource("MyAnimation") as Timeline;
image.BeginAnimation(a);
```

Comment: Thanks Vlad Will try out what you have suggested ?